# Using delegates with custom parameters in events

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have the code as seen below. The problem that I am having is that this part of the code gives a compilation error.

```
Changed(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(Operation.Add, e.Value, 1));
```

Error   1   Using the generic type 'CustomDatastructures.Core.ListChangedEventArgs' requires 1 type arguments

Second problem is how to call the onChanged method.

---

```
//public delegate void ListChanged<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
public delegate void BeforeListChanged<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
public delegate void ListChanged<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);

// Make this class generic by adding a type-parameter to the class
public class ObservableList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // Declare an private variabel to work as 
    // the internal data storage for the list
    List<T> observerList = new List<T>();

    public event ListChanged<ListChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed;
    //public event BeforeListChanged<T> BeforeChanged;

    protected virtual void OnChanged(object sender, Operation op, T value, int count)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(op, value, count));
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Add and object to the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">An object</param>
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        observerList.Add(item);
        OnChanged(this, Operation.Add, item, 1);
    }
```

This is the definition for the ListChangedEvent class

```
public class ListChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
public int Count { get; }
public Operation Operation { get; }
public T Value { get; }
public ListChangedEventArgs(Operation operation, T value, int count)
}
```

Comment: have you tried just parsing `e`? like this: `Changed(this, e);`

Comment: Doing that will give this: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'T'

Comment: I am trying to use this constructor in the custome events class. public ListChangedEventArgs(Operation operation, T value, int count)

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for something like `public delegate void ListChanged<TEventArgs>(object sender, EventArgs<TEventArgs> e);`? You get the exception because `ListChangedEventArgs<T>` is not `T` itself, as the second parameter to `Changed` has to be `T`.

Comment: public class ListChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
    public int Count { get; } 
    public Operation Operation { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
    public ListChangedEventArgs(Operation operation, T value, int count)
    }

Comment: Making the delegate public delegate void ListChanged<TEventArgs>(object sender, EventArgs<TEventArgs> e); will not work. It will give a compiler error. Error 2 The non-generic type 'System.EventArgs' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your `ObservableCollection` of type `T`. This collection has an event `ListChanged<T>`. But you call this event as if it is `ListChanged<ListChangedEventArgs<T>>`. So you have to change your event's declaration:

```
public event ListChanged<ListChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed;
protected virtual void OnChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs<T> e)
{
    if (Changed != null)
        Changed(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Using the non new instance version will generate this compiler error: Error 1 The non-generic type 'System.EventArgs' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @user2130951 Please update your question with the code that calls OnChanged or the event declaration of the event that OnChanged is supposed to handle.

Comment: Excellent that took me through problem number one. Problem number 2 is now in the question.

Comment: @user2130951 The event Changed is still declared as ListChanged<T> instead of ListChanged<ListChangedEventArgs<T>>.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39250/discussion-between-pvitt-and-user2130951)